# Heroku Postgres database values resetting on deployment

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am running a simple webapp on Heroku for splitting payments between housemates, and storing all payments to a Heroku PostgreSQL database.

The app works as expected while it is running, and the database is updated properly. However, after making changes to the code locally and pushing those to heroku, the database completely resets to a past instance, and all newly added rows are missing from the database.

Is this the intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

More details:
The app is a python app using the Flask framework

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working database on Heroku and want to seed it with some values, consider either using the seed file in the `db` folder of your Rails app or use `heroku run rails c` and then use the console to seed how you'd like.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in the original post, but I'm not trying to seed the database. I edited code unrelated to the database, and when I push it to heroku, the values in the database change.

Comment: are you running any tests that clean out the database, or scripts that restore snapshots from something like pgbackups? The database resetting "on its own" is not a feature of Heroku Postgres

Comment: So after looking into it a bit more, I've realized that any queries to the database to insert rows are not affecting the actual database (as far as I can see from the psql command line). However, while the app is live, the functionality is working, and if I modify the database from there (using psycopg2) it shows when I then run a select from psycopg 2.

Comment: Though it wasn't completely alluded to by my answer, the answer was inspired by the fact that I think you thought your Development DB and Production DB were the same, which they are in fact not.